# the url doesn't come right when I change form method from "post" to "get"

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form in a file called "report.inc" and after this form is filled and submitted the result is shown in a file called "report_result.inc".

form definition:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php?page=report_result">
```

When the form method is "post" all is ok.
after submitting the form, the page I get is with the right url:

mna.co.il/index.php?page=report_result

I wanted to see the whole url with all the sent parameters, so I changed the form method from "post" to "get" like this:

```
<form method="get" action="index.php?page=report_result">
```

and now after submitting the form, the page I get is with url that misses the part of "page=report_result".

it looks like this:

"http://mna.co.il/index.php?*locality*=%D7%91%D7%90%D7%A8&street=%D7%90%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%94%D7%9D&hNumber=55&rooms=3&area=70&ask=380000&smscode=&x=45&y=14"

while it should be like this:

"http://mna.co.il/index.php?**page=report_result** *&locality*=%D7%91%D7%90%D7%A8&street=%D7%90%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%94%D7%9D&hNumber=55&rooms=3&area=70&ask=380000&smscode=&x=45&y=14"

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for all answers.

Anna

Answer (score 9):

GET forms will wipe out any query string in their `action` when submitted. Use `<input type="hidden">` to pass the data instead.

Answer (score 4):

`page=report_result` is a GET parameter of the query so it's overridden by the params of your form if you use the GET method.
You should add the input

```
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="report_result" />
```

in your form and remove it from the `action`